# Delete a word and advance one space in vim

Tags: vim

I find myself often deleting a word `dw` but then advancing a space after doing that, for example to insert new text. An example might be (where `|` represents cursor):

```
 |2 colorscheme delek
```

- `2w` (advance two words)
- `dw` (delete word delek)
- `i` (insert at cursor)
- (space, advance one space)

Is there a more productive way to do the "delete + advance one space" pattern?

Comment: In your example, when you type `2w`, the cursor will be on `d`, then `dw` will remove the word `delek`, but the space between `..scheme` and `delek` will be kept. Do you really want to `i` a new space again?

Answer (score 3):

In your own steps, instead of `dw`, use `cw`. That will replace the word `delek`, keep the space, and leave you in insert-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using:

```
ciw  ..................... change the inner word
```